# How do I get hostname by sanic?

Tags: python, sanic

I am using [sanic](https://sanic.readthedocs.io) to create a API server but I can't find how to get the hostname on the docs.

Is there a reference of getting the hostname in sanic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is actually in the documentation:
[image]

https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/request_data.html

Comment: thank you. I should have looked in the request part